# TeamCity test id not available in API?

Tags: teamcity

In the TeamCity UI, when I look at the test history, I have the following URL:

https://teamcity.mydomain.com/test/7020533983586526163?currentProjectId=MyProject_Blah

Where can I find this id (7020533983586526163) using the TeamCity API? It doesn't seem available in `testOccurrences`.

For context, I'm working on a script to construct the URL to view the test history, but I can't seem to be able to back into that test id from any API route.

Answer (score 0):

In TeamCity REST API build has `testOccurrences` field of type `TestOccurrences﻿`, which in turn has a field `testOccurrence`, which is a list of `TestOccurrence`, which has a test id.

But remember that [you need to specify](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/teamcity-rest-api-documentation.html#Full+and+Partial+Responses) `fields` to fetch all this information. Otherwise, TeamCity REST API will only return the essential information.